# Video Capturing Using Python

Tags: opencv

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
```

what's the meaning of this or how it works?

Comment: Hi, Everything is explained here https://pythonprogramming.net/loading-video-python-opencv-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Import OpenCV

```
import cv2
```

Create a videocapture object to access to the camera of index -1, even though this is weird, usually you should set 0 for the default camera.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
```

Infinite loop over all frames of the video, at each iteration `frame` has the value of the current captured video frame

```
while(True):  
    ret, frame = cap.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down.

```
while(True):  
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

`while(True)` is effectively creating an infinite loop. The more generalized version of a while loop is `while(condition)`. In this case condition is always True and will continue running unless there is a break or return statement or you interrupt the execution from the operating system.

`cap.read()` returns two values: (1) a return value indicating if the read was successful and (2) the frame (image) that was read from the device.